# Dev-C++/TDM-GCC: Linkage Problems with Boost Libaries Downloaded from boost.org

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost, mingw

I'm trying to use `regex` in Dev-C++ (tdm-gcc 4.7.1).

I've downloaded Boost libraries from boost.org and unpack to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\boost
```

And in Dev-C++ added

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\boost\libs
```

to libraries.

Include paths (C/C++):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\boost
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 
using namespace boost; 
int main()
{
   string s ("some txt PING :665454 some_text");
   smatch mt;
  regex r ("PING :(\\d+) "); // error

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
D:\programowanie\dev-c++\main12\main.o  main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail27cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE[_ZN5boost9re_detail27cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE]+0xc3): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
D:\programowanie\dev-c++\main12\main.o  main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy]+0x60): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::resize(unsigned long long)'
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    main12/main.o: bad reloc address 0x60 in section `.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy]'
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    final link failed: Invalid operation
D:\programowanie\dev-c++\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need to link to boost regex, possibly in the compiler options for Dev-C++ (haven't used Dev-C++ in years, sorry). Possibly search for a Other Linker Options and type in -lboost_regex.

Comment: Also if you need regex, you could use the new [regular expressions library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library in the new C++11 standard library. Oh, and don't use [`system("pause");`](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you could have downloaded binaries from Boost exactly targeting TDM-GCC. As a result, no matter what, you'll hit a classical problem with **[name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)** which is different across compilers/toolchains. If you downloaded from **[Boost binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.54.0/)**, then it's clearly written that these binaries were built with MSVC, and therefore now you have trouble directly linking to these Boost libraries with TDM-GCC because of different name mangling conventions.

You have 3 options:

1. Use MSVC to build your project;
2. Build Boost libraries from source yourself with **your current** toolchain, i.e. TDM-GCC;
3. Use my builds of Boost libraries - **[Boost for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/boost-for-windows)** (latest version is 1.54.0) for latest **[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)** toolchains (currently 2 variants). So, in addition to binaries, you'd have to download the corresponding toolchain variant of MinGW-w64 (link are there as well) and use it to build your project.

   **NOTE:** Although you can build and link your project against my binaries with your TDM-GCC because name mangling is the same (since TDM-GCC is just a derivative of MinGW-w64), the resulting application will be subject to crashes as binaries produced by MinGW-w64 are binary incompatible with TDM-GCC due to patching policies of TDM-GCC.

Finally, as stated in comments already, it's not enough just to set paths where Boost libraries can be found, but it is also necessary to explicitly tell the compiler which library you want to link your project against. For the GCC family of compilers (MinGW, MinGW-w64, TDM-GCC) it is done with the `-l` switch. So find where you can specify linker options in Dev-C++ for your project, and add `-lboost_regex`. It will instruct the compiler to fetch `libboost_regex.a` from the library search paths (that you've already specified) and link to your project.

Comment: c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe cannot find -lboost_regex

Mhm... i only downloaded boost_1_54_0.zip

Comment: Do you realize that you've downloaded the source code? So it's not even prebuilt binaries, i.e. you don't even have Boost libraries to link with, yet. First, you have to build Boost libraries on your own or if that sounds frustrating to you (and I expect that it will be tough for you, since I already see that you're quite new too all of that), then you could follow my suggestion #3. Good luck.

Comment: I downlodaded boosts from dev paks, but it doesnt working too mhm. Sorry, i dont saw your comment

Comment: It is possible to download compiled code for gcc, and only set folders?:p